# JS adding a number to a class (classname+number)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax

There's a problem somewhere in ".addClass('clicked'+'nb')
my css classes are named "clicked1" "clicked2" etc.
I tried 'clicked1' and 'clicked2' and they work, but I'd like it to work with the "nb" that is collected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.boxes').on('click', '.box', function() {

        var data = $(this).data('nb');

        var tekst = $('.wrapper');
        tekst.addClass('clicked'+'nb');/*'clicked1' is a css class, same with clicked2,3...*/
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yujtvd66/2/

Comment: You probably want to use `data` instead of `'nb'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/yujtvd66/3/) with the code i think you're looking for.

```
$('.wrapper').removeClass()
    .addClass('wrapper')
    .addClass('clicked'+data);
```

Comment: Please upvote and mark as answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are getting the data of the element to the `data` variable.

```
var data = $(this).data('nb');
```

You need to use that variable wherever you want to use your data.

```
tekst.addClass('clicked' + data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.boxes').on('click', '.box', function() { 
        var data = $(this).attr('data-nb');
        var tekst = $('.wrapper');
        tekst.addClass('clicked'+data); 
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dineshpatra28/yujtvd66/4/)

Comment: `$(this).data('nb')` instead of `$(this).attr('data-nb')`