# another addClass, moving div with left

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

[Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/nr681upv/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  console.log("Doc is ready.");

  $('.tab-holder').on('click', '.tab', function() {

    console.log("Function is running.");

    var data = $(this).data('nb');

    $('.blok').removeClass()
      .addClass('blok')
      .addClass('blokwybrany' + data)
    console.log("Classname:", 'blokWybrany' + data);
  });
});
```

It worked before, but i messed something up after changing my divs.
Anyway someone has told me to use jQuery animate instead. Dunno what to do. Isn't it the proper way to do this ?

Comment: the previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844705/js-adding-a-number-to-a-class-classnamenumber

i tried recreating it for learning purposes and i don't know what's wrong

Comment: @mokiSRB there's a Snippet

Comment: Can you please give us the intended result. Your code doesn't give me a clear direction of what you need done.

Comment: Ofc. I want to manipulate with `#blok`'s `left` so it goes left and right according to the pressed tab.

If you change `#blok { left: 0% / -100% / -200% / -300% / -400% / -500% ;}` it will move the parent and the according children will appear on the screen.(later on with a sliding transition)